# Array pushes elements already in Array despite !arry.includes

Tags: reactjs, arrays, firebase

I am trying to build an app that requires a directory. Every time I update the component, it pushes the data into the array again creating multiple copies. I tried solving that by adding an !arry.includes, but that does not stop it for adding another occurrence of the data.

```
 const Directory = () => {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const data = async () => {
      const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("type", "==", "doctor"));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        if (!searchResults.includes(data)) {
          searchResults.push(data);
        }
      });
      setLoading(false);
    };
    data();
  },[]);
  console.log(searchResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to compare objects here which doesn't work with the array.includes() method.

In javascript

```js
const user1 = {name : "nerd", org: "dev"};
const user2 = {name : "nerd", org: "dev"};
user1 == user2; // is false
```

You would need to search for something more specific or try [Comparing Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript). Either way what your trying to do is tricky and you may need to explore [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or something to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way!

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const data = async () => {
      const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("type", "==", "doctor"));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const notInArray = searchResults.some(u => u.uid === data.uid);
        console.log(notInArray);
        if (notInArray === false) {
          searchResults.push(data)
        }
      });
      setLoading(false);
    };
    return () => {
      data();
    };
  }, []);
```